EasyNetQ ErrorQueueNamingConvention together with quorum queues
I'm using classic queues today but want to start moving to quorum queues (because classic queues aren't supported anymore).
I have a custom error strategy (DefaultConsumerErrorStrategy) and error queue naming convention. My surveillance setup is tied to this naming convention so I'd like to keep it the way it is.
This is how it looks like:
var conv = (Conventions) Bus.Container.Resolve<IConventions>();
conv.ErrorExchangeNamingConvention = x => $"{x.Queue}_error";
conv.ErrorQueueNamingConvention = x => $"{x.Queue}_error";

Works like a charm with classic queues.
It actually also "works" with quorum queues, problem is the _error queue is created as a classic queue.
I would like the error queue to be of the same type as the queue that failed.
I haven't tried changing the default queue type to quorum because I'm afraid this will cause problems while I'm transitioning to quorum queues. I'm not explicitly setting the type for my old queues to classic.
I have 2 questions:

How can I make the error queue type the same as the failing queue?
How are you handling error queues? Should I do it differently although I'd have to change my surveillance setup?

